# Teradata - JDBC connection using kerberos

Tags: database, jdbc, teradata, kerberos

I need help in creating JDBC connection with Teradata  using Kerberos  authentication.

I have already gone through documentation but it is not complete,
http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#CCHCBHJI

but can some share source code and steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched over to kerberos authentication about 6 months ago, and it took a lot of reading, trial, and error, so be prepared to spend a considerable amount of time on this. We use jdbc only for connecting Aqua Data Studio to Teradata, none of our production jobs use jdbc. With that context, this is an overview of the setup we need to do when doing a fresh install (yours will be different, I'm sure):

1. Add java properties (update the paths below as needed for your system)

```
<string>-Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true</string>
<string>-Djava.security.krb5.realm=YOUR_REALM_HERE</string>
<string>-Djava.security.krb5.kdc=THIS_WAS_THE_SAME_AS_REALM_FOR_US</string>
<string>-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf</string>
<string>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/jaas.conf</string>
<string>-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false</string>
```

Create a jaas.conf file in the location referenced above with this:

```
JaasClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true useTicketCache=true;
};
```

To create a ticket, you'll run

```
kinit -f
```

For us, our tickets expire every 10 hours, ymmv.

You'll also need to install JCE Unlimited Strength for Java.
Download "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" appropriate for your java version. 
You can find the files here for [Java 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) or [Java 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).

Unzip the file and replace these 2 files: US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar in  /path/to/your/.../java/jre/lib/security with the downloaded files. If you are seeing the error message "unsupported key type found the default TGT: 18" this could be an indication that you do not have the Unlimited strength policy files installed.

One last step -- we had to add these parameters to the jdbc driver: TMODE=TERA,LOGMECH=KRB5. In Aqua Data Studio, we now leave the username and password blank when initiating the connection.

Good luck!

Helpful links:

[Aqua Data Studio specific, but maybe helpful for others](http://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation18/page/Kerberos-Configuration/Kerberos-Configuration)

[Cloudera page about JCE Unlimited Strength for Java](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_sg_jce_policy_file_install.html)